# Why does "git status" show way too much untracked files?

Tags: git, git-status

**Answer in the bottom.**

I am trying to see the `status` of my files in the `git_test2` directory which contains 3 files named `test1.txt`, `test2.txt` and `test3.txt`.

This is what I typed into Terminal:

```
cd Desktop
cd git_test2
git status
```

Everything is good until the `git status` command. It should show me just 3 untracked files but instead I get this text from the Terminal:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

new file:   ../../AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine/app/src/main/res/layout/list_item_forecast.xml
new file:   ../../Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio1.2/options/fileEditorProviderManager.xml
new file:   ../../Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio1.2/options/git.xml
new file:   ../../Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio1.2/options/other.xml
new file:   ../../Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio1.2/options/runner.layout.xml

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   ../../AndroidStudioProjects/Sunshine/app/src/main/res/layout/list_item_forecast.xml
modified:   ../../Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio1.2/options/runner.layout.xml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

../../.CFUserTextEncoding
../../.Rsupport/
```

and after the last line there are many lines just like the last one (in red color)

I just found out the reason:
All I needed to do is `git init`, now it shows exactly what I expected. Thank you everyone!

Comment: run `pwd` in the same directory where you operate Git. What does it return?

Comment: @NickVolynkin `/Users/ishayfrenkel1/Desktop/git_test2`

Comment: That's just half of a solution. See the answer )

Comment: by `cd git status` did you mean `git status` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Yes, that's a typo only in the forum

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Why are there so many files?

A git repository is just a `.git/` directory (folder) located in your project's directory. Like this: `myproject/.git/`.

If there's no git repository in your current directory, git **searches in the parent directory, then in parent's parent and up to top**.

As your path was `/Users/ishayfrenkel1/Desktop/git_test2`, there should be a git repo somewhere in this path.

```
new file:   ../../Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio1.2/options/git.xml
```

New files have path at least two levels up from `/Library` (which is either `/Library` or `/Users/ishayfrenkel1/Library`). It means that you have a git repository initiated:

- either in your home directory: `~/`, `/Users/<username>/` on OSX or `/home/<username>` on Linux.
- or in the root directory, `/`, the parent of all directories.

#### How it happened.

Most probably you opened the Terminal and typed `git init`. Terminal opens in your home directory by default and that's where the new repository was created.

#### What to do now.

Search for it and delete it. One of the following commands should run without an error. And there it is!

```
ls /.git
ls ~/.git
```

Now remove the repository with

```
rm -rf ~/.git
```

Comment: Delete what?
I did `git add` only after `git init`.

Comment: I suppose you've got a git repository initiated somewhere in the root folder. It explains why you got so many untracked files all over your filesystem.

Comment: This has just got a "Nice Answer" badge so I updated it with more niceness. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm i looks a bit that you have your `.git` folder not in your product but i few folder above. Then when you are in your project and you make a git status and you see `../../` that means that you are on the second level in your Git repository.

Perhaps you should clone that repository again and check you git structure.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, file paths starts with `../..`.
Git status always shows *all* changes in current repositroty, not only in current directory. As you see, it actually shows changes in repository, in which you are at least 2 folders deep. But there are no files `test1.txt`.

So, check with `pwd` that you're in right directory (maybe you're in another repo currently).