# Why am I getting an entire list of my computers contents when I clone a repository

Tags: git

I am trying to simply clone a git repository with `git clone` and then ask for a status update which should give me this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

when however after I have done this I get:

```
$ git status
warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Cookies/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Local Settings/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'NetHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'PrintHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Recent/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Start Menu/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Templates/': Permission denied
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   CS1998-puzzle-repo

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .anaconda/
        .bash_history
        .cisco/
        .conda/
        .condarc
        .gitconfig
        .idlerc/
        .ipynb_checkpoints/
        .ipython/
        .jupyter/
        .matplotlib/
        .minttyrc
        .spyder-py3/
        3D Objects/
        Anaconda3/
        AppData/
        Contacts/
        Desktop/
        Documents/
        Downloads/
        Dropbox/
        Favorites/
        Google Drive/
        IntelGraphicsProfiles/
        Learning .ipynb
        Learning Variables.ipynb
        Links/
        MicrosoftEdgeBackups/
        Music/
        NTUSER.DAT
        NTUSER.DAT{d0151108-541c-11ea-a1f7-b1e0d7960e94}.TM.blf
        NTUSER.DAT{d0151108-541c-11ea-a1f7-b1e0d7960e94}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{d0151108-541c-11ea-a1f7-b1e0d7960e94}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
        OneDrive/
        Pictures/
        Saved Games/
        Searches/
        Untitled.ipynb
        Untitled1.ipynb
        Untitled2.ipynb
        Videos/
        ntuser.dat.LOG1
        ntuser.dat.LOG2
        ntuser.ini
        opera autoupdate/
        projectpart1/
```

I have tried cloning it multiple times, I have read the git documentation and a few other related stack posts but I can't get it to work properly. Thus I want to get rid of all the unnecessary red files and just get the clone to work properly.

Comment: It seems like you've accidentally created a repo in your home directory.

Comment: Thats what I think I have done from the other stack post, which is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476240/why-does-git-status-show-way-too-much-untracked-files/30485085 but I don't rly understand what the confirmed answer is saying how to fix it,

as you can tell I am extremely new to this

Comment: What is unclear from *"What to do now"*? Find and delete the `.git` directory in your home directory.

Comment: I have a .gitconfig, but that didnt do anything

Comment: its okay I got it, I didnt have my settings enabled to show hidden files so the .git files werent there, thank you anyway

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Error: Permission denied on status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614164/github-error-permission-denied-on-status)